# JAR file Database connection

Tags: database, jar

a Database acces and Search Program.

1. a JAR file make use Windows command
2. a JAR file make use Eclipse Export->Jar file

run as 1 ... that run

run as 2 ... that error -> database connection NULL

1 source file and 2 source file same directory position, same files

please tell me , How I do about case 2 ??

.. I used library classes12.jar

Answer (score 1):

download mysql-connector-java-5.1.16-bin.jar

If you have then set as an **external** jar file in the libraries section of Eclipse->Project->Properties->Java Build Path. Then make jar.Hope it helps.

Comment: For oracle I hope procedure is same.The real difference is ** external **

Comment: I was that way, but database connection is null.  Why don't realize to classes12.jar files in jar file(export from Eclipse) ... ??

Comment: Here is a link for you.>> http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14545_01/help/oracle.eclipse.tools.database.doc/html/gettingStarted/files/gettingStarted.html     and again this problem is created due to folder organization.